# Installed ATI Proprietary driver, can't get 3d acceleration

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

Using the guide: http://wiki.debian.org/ATIProprietary
I did the following steps:

```
1) aptitude install --without-recommends linux-headers-$(uname -r)
2) aptitude install fglrx-control fglrx-driver
3) aticonfig --initial
```

I can run xwindow and control the fan speed, catalyst control center also loads up. Video card is HD 5770. I installed the proprietary drive because I want to control the fan speed.

However, when I login, the background wallpaper rendering is lagging (sort of looks like a vsync issue). When playing flash 1080p videos, it is very choppy and uses high cpu.

Running **fglrxinfo** shows the following:

```
display: :0.0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: ATI Radeon HD 5700 Series
OpenGL version string: 4.0.10188 Compatibility Profile Context
```

The device section of **xorg.conf** looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        Option      "Monitor-DFP1" "0-DFP1"
        Option      "Monitor-DFP3" "0-DFP3"
        Option      "UseFastTLS" "1"
        Option      "VideoOverlay" "off"
        Option      "TexturedVideo" "on"
        Option      "OpenGLOverlay" "off"
        Option      "TexturedVideoSync" "on"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0" EndSection
```

Running fgl_glxgears shows `using glx_sgix_pbuffer and renders 1268FPS`
Running fgl_glxgears with `-fbo switch shows using gl_ext_framebuffer and renders 2200FPS`

Running glxinfo | grep rendering shows

```
direct rendering: Yes
```

Running glxinfo | grep direct:

```
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect, GL_ARB_draw_instanced, 
    GL_EXT_copy_buffer, GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_direct_state_access,
```

When I do video info on 1080p youtube videos, it says software rendering and software decoding. Running fglx_gear also uses high cpu. html5 videos are using high cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a common problem with Linux based systems, the drivers written for it are either written by ATI or other developers and dont get updated quite often and hence the performance issues, my ATI Mobility 550v has similar performance issues due to lack of good driver support, I cant really help you solve this problem, you can just hope you get better driver support going forward.